# Excel VBA - "Type Mismatch" on second SET shape

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small macro, but get a Type 13 mismatch (run-time error 13) on only the second 'Set shape' line.  I get no errors on the first one, but can't figure why I'm getting an error on the second.  AFAIK it's doing the exact same thing?

```
Sub myMacro()
Dim mapWS, dataWS As Worksheet
Dim fromX, fromY, toX, toY As Integer
Dim fromShape, toShape As Shape

Set mapWS = Sheets("World Map")
Set dataWS = Sheets("Data")


Dim shapeNames(2, 2) As String
shapeNames(0, 0) = "USA"
shapeNames(0, 1) = "USA2"
shapeNames(1, 0) = "Germany"
shapeNames(1, 1) = "DEU"

i = 0
Set fromShape = mapWS.Shapes.Range(Array(shapeNames(i, 1)))
Set toShape = mapWS.Shapes.Range(Array(shapeNames(i + 1, 1)))
...
End Sub
```

The error occurs when at the second line ("Set toShape = mapWS...").  Why does it occur there - or the inverse, why doesn't it occur on the first one? Can you only set one shape range at a time?

Thanks for any help or any ideas!

Comment: When you dim your vars like `Dim mapWS, dataWS As Worksheet`, only `dataWS` is declared as a worksheet. The `mapWS` becomes a variant. The same holds true for fromShape, toShape and the others.

Comment: Ooooohhhh, I did not know that.  That's interesting.  (...and now I get to go back and touch up other macros that I used that format for ["Dim x, y, z  as integer"]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware, with the syntax below, in VBA, your first object `fromShape` is variant, and the second one is `Shape`:

```
Dim fromShape, toShape As Shape
```

*If you want both Shape, you have to write: `Dim fromShape As Shape, toShape As Shape`*

So, in your first line:

```
Set fromShape = mapWS.Shapes.Range(Array(shapeNames(i, 1)))
```

You affect the result of a Range object to a variant. That's fine.

But in your second line:

```
Set toShape = mapWS.Shapes.Range(Array(shapeNames(i + 1, 1)))
```

You affect the result of a Range object to a Shape object... and then "Type Mismatch".

You'd rather let VBA decide and then declare both variables as Variant:

```
Dim fromShape, toShape
```

Thanks to Rory comment, if you want true typed variable, you'll have to use:

```
Dim fromShape As ShapeRange, toShape As ShapeRange
```

Comment: It's not a `Range` object, it's a `ShapeRange` object - they are quite different. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you actually want `Shape` objects, it would, IMO, be better to use them:

```
Dim fromShape As Shape, toShape As Shape
...

i = 0
Set fromShape = mapWS.Shapes(shapeNames(i, 1))
Set toShape = mapWS.Shapes(shapeNames(i + 1, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks Rory - I got the whole "Array(shapeNames..." by doing a Macro and using that - the macro Excel creates used the Array, but you're right, I'd want to be using a Shape.

Comment: Hm -- using ShapeRange I get a new error ("Run-time error 424: Object Required).  Here's the line:    Set fromShape = mapsWS.Shapes(shapeNames(k, 1)) .. ....also doesn't work with the Array option. How do I get it to set the Shape variable?

Comment: You didn't replace **all** your code with what I posted did you? I only showed the lines that needed to change.

Comment: Ah yes, fixed it up and it works.  But, using "ShapeRange" instead of "Shape", would I need to use the "Array" method, as in my original post --- and using just "Shape" I just use mapWS.Shapes() ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `Shapes.Range()` will return a `ShapeRange` object (even if it's only one shape) whereas `Shapes()` returns a `Shape` object.